# sqlalchemy, why relationship is not established

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to create one to one relationship. Why the output is None?

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, Float
from sqlalchemy import Sequence
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship, backref


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')#, echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('user_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'item'
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(Float, default=0)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id))
    user = relationship("User", backref=backref('itemA', uselist=False))

    def __init__(self, id, value, user_id = None):
        self.id = id
        self.value = value
        self.user_id = user_id


session = Session()
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
ed_user = User('ed')
session.add(ed_user)

session.flush()
it1 = Item('it1', 1, user_id='ed')

session.add(it1)
session.flush()

print  it1.user
print  ed_user.itemA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You give `User` an (autoincrementing) integer ID (primary key) and refer to it from `Item`. But then you pass user's `name` (a string!) to the newly created `Item` instead of ID. With most database engines this code would just blow up. But SQLite:

1. [Does not enforce](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) foreign key constraints by default.
2. Has a loose [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

So it fails silently.

You should pass an actual ID instead.

```
it1 = Item('it1', 1, ed_user.id)
```

Or assign the `User` object itself to relationship:

```
it1 = Item('it1', 1)
it1.user = ed_user
```

The former requires the session to be flushed to get the ID value assigned by the database. The latter "just works": SQLAlchemy resolves the data dependencies automatically.